# SAPUI5 - Add more elements to view

Tags: javascript, sapui5

i'm trying to create something like logon screen. One input field for name and one input field for password. I doing it via view and shell. Here's what i've got.

app.js:

```
var myView = new sap.ui.view({
    viewName: "myapp.view.My",
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS
});

var oShell = new sap.m.Shell("mainShell", {
    app: myView
});

oShell.placeAt("content");
```

My.view.js:

```
sap.ui.jsview("myapp.view.My", {
    createContent: function(oController) {

        var oNameInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField();
        var oPasswordInput = new sap.ui.commons.TextField();

        return oNameInput, oPasswordInput;
    }
});
```

the problem is that only one field is showing, or the second one is on the first one. What is the logic of adding more elements to the view? Thanks.

Comment: try the `sap.ui.layout`-library (at the beginning especially the HorizontalLayout and the VerticalLayout) https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.html

Comment: About the layout, is there something like creating layout in android? I mean the xml file.

Comment: I don't know much about android-development, but you can use [XML-Views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f292806f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are actually returning the first element only.
Return it as an array :

```
[oNameInput, oPasswordInput]
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I second herrlocks´s comment. You should include the `sap.ui.layout`-library and arrange those two elements into a layout object of your choice[1]. Then, you return the single layout object, which is containing your name and password input objects, instead.

[1] https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.html